# Best way to handle concatenating string with another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on cleaning up some adopted code - there is a lot of duplication.

There is a set of jQuery callbacks where we get back JSON like this:

```
[
{"location":{"id":164,"name":"place 1"},"users":[{"id":1,"name":"joe"},{"id":2,"name":"jack"}]},
{"location":{"id":162,"name":"place 2"},"users":[{"id":3,"name":"joe"},{"id":4,"name":"jon"}]}
]
```

I go through with these functions:

```
function locations_view(r) {
    str = "";

    $.each(r.data, function(k, v) {
        str += v.location.name + "<br />";
        iterate_users(v.users);
    });

    $("#locations").html(str);
} 

function iterate_users(users) {
    str += '<strong>users:</strong>' + users.length + '<br />';

    $.each(users, function(k1, v1) {
        str += "<a href='/users/" + v1.id + "'>" + v1.name + "</a> ";   
    });

    str += "<br />";
}
```

This seems to work but it looks a little ugly. Is there a better way to do this. Also, I want to minimize memory consumption (returning the string rather than have a global `str` was causing performance issues). Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? Would having multiple copies of `str` ever cause a problem? Like if I have products_view that also uses a `str`?

Comment: using globals is always discouraged. i dont know why it would cause a big performance change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if something else uses `str` in the wrong way (i.e. also globally) then that will cause a problem. Best not to have any globals at all. You could change them to this:

```
function locations_view(r) {
    var str = "";

    $.each(r.data, function(k, v) {
        str += v.location.name + "<br />";
        str += iterate_users(v.users);
    });

    $("#locations").html(str);
} 

function iterate_users(users) {
    var str = '<strong>users:</strong>' + users.length + '<br />';

    $.each(users, function(k1, v1) {
        str += "<a href='/users/" + v1.id + "'>" + v1.name + "</a> ";   
    });

    return str + "<br />";
}
```

And that would be much better. If there are other functions that use `iterate_users`, they'll need to be changed too.

Also, if you're not already doing this, consider escaping the HTML in `v1.name` to prevent script injection. You could also use jQuery/DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: I would think the str problem would happen but I reloaded like 20 times and wasn't able to get it to do that. Just one example but curious if javascript engine is able to manage that correctly. Intuitively, I would agree with you. In original question, I was getting problems due to passing the str as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit faster doing concatenation in one step, like

```
function locations_view(r) {
    var peices = [], br = "<br />";

    $.each(r.data, function(k, v) {
        peices.push(v.location.name, br);
        peices.push.apply(peices, iterate_users(v.users));
    });

    $("#locations").html(peices.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code:

```
function locations_view(r){
    var str = ""; // don't forget var
    $.each(r.data, function(k,v){
        str += v.location.name + "<br />";
        str += iterate_users(v.users);  // iterate_users now returns a string, concat it
    });
    $("#locations").html(str);
} 

function iterate_users(users){
    var str = '<strong>users:</strong>' + users.length + '<br />'; // redefine str locally
    $.each(users, function (k1,v1){
        str += '<a href="/users/' + v1.id + '">' + v1.name + '</a> '; // flipped use of ' and ", it's more correct
    });
    return str + "<br />"; // return str
}
```

I don't see much wrong with it. I suppose there might be more efficient ways to do it, buy why? This seems like a decent and most importantly: **obvious** way to do it.

Also, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), it will hurt your feelings but save you headaches

Answer (score 0):

```
function locations_view(r) {

    var $loc = $("#locations");

    $.each(r.data, function (k, v) {

        $loc.append(v.location.name + "<br/>");
        $loc.append('<strong>users:</strong>' + v.users.length + '<br />');
        $.each(v.users, function (k1, v1) {
           $loc.append("<a href='/users/" + v1.id + "'>" + v1.name + "</a> ");
        });
        $loc.append("<br />");

    });
}
```